# unable to update role and stripe plan rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, roles, stripe-payments, rolify

I'm attempting to update my stripe subscription via and edit page but it doesn't seem to like whatever i throw at it.

Here is my routes.rb

```
get 'subscribe' => 'subscribe#stepone'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale' => 'subscribe#steptwo'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale/subscriber' => 'subscribe#subscriber'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale/supporter' => 'subscribe#supporter'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale/sustainer' => 'subscribe#sustainer'
  post 'subscribe/sliding-scale/:type' => 'subscribe#createSubscription'
  get 'subscribe/edit' => 'subscribe#edit', :as => :edit_subscription
  match '/subscribe/edit', to: 'subscribe#deleteCard', via: :delete
  match '/subscribe/edit', to: 'subscribe#updateSubscription', via: :post
  post 'subscribe/edit/changeSubscription' => 'subscribe#changeSubscription', :as => :change_subscription
```

My subscription controller:

```
def changeSubscription
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripeCustomerId)
    @plan = params[:plan]
    @user.update_subscription(:plan => @plan, :prorate => true)
    current_role = @user.roles.first.name
    @user.remove_role current_role
    current_user.add_role params[@plan]
  end
```

and lastly my edit view:

```
 <h2>Change My Subscription</h2>
  <h3>Your current plan is: <%= current_user.roles.first.name %>
  <%= select_tag @plan, options_for_select([['Subscriber'], ['Sustainer'], ['Supporter']]) %>
  <%= link_to "Update", change_subscription_path, :confirm => "You sure?", :plan => @plan %>
```

I'm attempting to send the new plan to the controller to update both the local role and the plan but it seems not to be able to find the proper route to do so. Not sure what i'm doing wrong in this regard.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform a `POST` request to  `change_subscription_path`, but you're requesting the page with a simple link_to so it's a `GET` request.

Add `:method => :post` in your `link_to` options:

```
<%= link_to "Update", change_subscription_path, :confirm => "You sure?", :method => :post, :plan => @plan %>
```

Alternatively, you can:

- use a form instead of a link and submit it with the `POST` method
- change the method for the `changeSubscription` action from `POST` to `GET` in routes.rb